# using python to solve a nonlinear equation

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, nonlinear-functions

I have never used python but Mathematica can't handle the equation I am trying to solve.  I am trying to solve for the variable "a" of the following equations where s, c, mu, and delta t are known parameters.

[image]

I tried doing NSolve, Solve, etc in Mathematica but it has been running for an hour with no luck.  Since I am not familiar with Python, is there a way I can use Python to solve this equation for a?

Comment: Could you give an example input and output?

Comment: @Serdalis what do you mean?

Comment: this is quite complex and it would greatly help anyone who is trying to recreate it if you provided an example of the formula in action. Nothing so grand as working out, but a solution for a set of values would be quite useful.

Comment: @Serdalis the formula is the last line of the code.  The two lines above are the definitions for alpha and beta inside the formula s = 10014.6, c = 6339.06, mu = 398600, delta t = 780, and a is what I want to find.

Comment: Well, if `s/(2*a)` and `(s-c)/(2*a)` are each between -1 and 1, then `sin(alpha)` and `sin(beta)` can be expressed algebraically. Other than that...maybe compute some Taylor polynomials (which will be messy) and see if they give you any approximate solutions? If Mathematica is choking on it, then rolling your own code to find a solution will be extremely difficult at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to find an analytic solution to these equations because they're transcendental, containing `a` both inside and outside of a trigonometric function.

I think the trouble you're having with numerical solutions is that the range of acceptable values for `a` is constrained by the `arcsin`. Since `arcsin` is only defined for arguments between -1 and 1 (assuming you want `a` to be real), your formulas for `alpha` and `beta` require that `a > s/2` and `a > (s-c)/2`.

In Python, you can find a zero of your third equation (rewritten in the form `f(a) = 0`) using the `brentq` function:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import brentq

s = 10014.6
c = 6339.06
mu = 398600.0
dt = 780.0
def f(a):
    alpha = 2*np.arcsin(np.sqrt(s/(2*a)))
    beta = 2*np.arcsin(np.sqrt((s-c)/(2*a)))
    return alpha - beta - (np.sin(alpha)-np.sin(beta)) - np.sqrt(mu/a**3)*dt

a0 = max(s/2, (s-c)/2)
a = brentq(f, a0, 10*a0)
```

**Edit:**

To clarify the way `brentq(f,a,b)` works is that it searches for a zero of `f` on an interval `[a,b]`. Here, we know that `a` is at least `max(s/2, (s-c)/2)`. I just guessed that 10 times that was a plausible upper bound, and that worked for the given parameters. More generally, you need to make sure that `f` changes sign between `a` and `b`. You can read more about how the function works in the [SciPy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html).

Comment: Why did you need to define a0 and then say brentq(f,a0,10*a0)?  I am asking because I have never used Python, and I would like to know why so I could try on my own if something like this is encountered again.

Comment: The way brentq works is that it starts at a (here a0) and looks for a zero of the given f function between a (here a0) and b (10*a0). Defining a0 is necessary because the brentq function needs a place to start looking for zeros. As Ray mentioned, this is explained in the [documentation for the brentq function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think its worth examining the behaviour of the function before atempting to solve it. Without doing that you dont know if there is a unique solution, many solutions, or no solution. (The biggest problem is many solutions, where numerical methods may not give you the solution you require/expect - and if you blindly use it "bad things" might happen). You examine the behaviour nicely using scipy and ipython. This is an example notebook that does that

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# <nbformat>3.0</nbformat>

# <codecell>

s = 10014.6
c = 6339.06
mu = 398600.0
dt = 780.0

# <codecell>

def sin_alpha_2(x):
    return numpy.sqrt(s/(2*x))
def sin_beta_2(x):
    return numpy.sqrt((s-c)/(2*x))
def alpha(x):
    return 2*numpy.arcsin( numpy.clip(sin_alpha_2(x),-0.99,0.99) )
def beta(x):
    return 2*numpy.arcsin( numpy.clip(sin_beta_2(x),-0.99,0.99) )

# <codecell>

def fn(x):
    return alpha(x)-beta(x)-numpy.sin(alpha(x))+numpy.sin(beta(x)) - dt * numpy.sqrt( mu / numpy.power(x,3) )

# <codecell>

xx = numpy.arange(1,20000)
pylab.plot(xx, numpy.clip(fn(xx),-2,2) )
```

[image: Graph of fn]

```
# <codecell>

xx=numpy.arange(4000,10000)
pylab.plot(xx,fn(xx))
```

[image]

```
# <codecell>

xx=numpy.arange(8000,9000)
pylab.plot(xx,fn(xx))
```

[image]

This shows that we expect to find a solution with a between 8000 and 9000.
The odd kink in the curve at about 5000 and earlier solution at about 4000 is due to 
the clipping required to make arcsin behave. Really the equation does not make sense below about a=5000. (exact value is the a0 given in Rays solution). This then gives a nice range that can be used with the techniques in Rays solution.

Comment: It doesn't make sense because below 5017 I believe the concentric circles of the orbits don't intersect.  This was part of an orbital mechanics problem so we are solving for the semi major axis that cause the object to transfer to the point p2 in 780 secs of 13mins.