# running python on vim

Tags: vim, python-2.7, numpy, ubuntu-12.04, ipython

Over on askubuntu.com I was told how to [run python on Vim](https://askubuntu.com/questions/273066/running-python-in-vim/273068?noredirect=1#comment344013_273068).  I am testing the set up which works with the code 1st or 2nd code python code at [using python to solve a non linear equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649134/using-python-to-solve-a-nonlinear-equation/15652210?noredirect=1#15652210).

The only thing I have done different was added print(a) as the last line.  I ran this yesterday from the shell and it worked perfectly.  Could someone let me know what is going wrong?

Ok so I corrected the vimrc with the appropriate question marks,

```
chmod +x ~/path/to/file/hw6problem2.py
```

Then from vim I ran

```
:Shell ./#
```

but I received the same syntax error again. **(Does the file have to be saved as .sh because I can't get any .py files to run?)**

```
dustin@dustin:~$ vim /home/dustin/Documents/School/UVM/Engineering/OrbitalMechanics/hw6problem2.py

File "hw6problem2.py", line 14
a0 = max(s/2, (s - c)/2)
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

vimrc

```
syntax on
au BufWinLeave * mkview "records settings
au BufWinEnter * silent loadview "reloads settings


set nu "puts line numbers on
set ic "case insensitive
set foldmethod=syntax "for the latex-suite
set autoread "autoload when files in the buffer have been modified
set autochdir "autochange directory


"set wrap
set wrap
" set lines=50 columns=80

" resizes window
:map g1 :set lines=20<CR>:set columns=80<CR>
:map g2 :set lines=50<CR>:set columns=80<CR>
:map g3 :set lines=50<CR>:set columns=170<CR>
:map <F6> :! firefox % &<CR>
:map E Ea

"set autoindent

set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
set smartindent
"
" Stuff for latex-suite 

" REQUIRED. This makes vim invoke Latex-Suite when you open a tex file.
" It also allows you to set different actions for different filetypes
" in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/*.vim
filetype plugin on

set shellslash

" IMPORTANT: grep will sometimes skip displaying the file name if you
" search in a singe file. This will confuse Latex-Suite. Set your grep
" program to always generate a file-name.
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*

" OPTIONAL: This enables automatic indentation as you type.
filetype indent on

" OPTIONAL: Starting with Vim 7, the filetype of empty .tex files defaults to
" 'plaintex' instead of 'tex', which results in vim-latex not being loaded.
" The following changes the default filetype back to 'tex':
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'okular'


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Shell command
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:RunShellCommand(<q-args>)

function! s:RunShellCommand(cmdline)
let isfirst = 1
let words = []
for word in split(a:cmdline)
if isfirst
  let isfirst = 0  " don't change first word (shell command)
 else
  if word[0] =~ '\v[%#<]'
    let word = expand(word)
  endif
  let word = shellescape(word, 1)
endif
call add(words, word)
endfor
let expanded_cmdline = join(words)
rightbelow new
setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap
call setline(1, 'You entered:  ' . a:cmdline)
call setline(2, 'Expanded to:  ' . expanded_cmdline)
call append(line('$'), substitute(getline(2), '.', '=', 'g'))
silent execute '$read !'. expanded_cmdline
1
endfunction
```

Comment: Could you post some code around line 14?

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with Vim.  There's nothing wrong with that one line of Python, either.  Please either post the entire Python file (or link to a gist of it if it's large), or more context.  I suspect you're just introducing a typo or something.

Comment: @PavelAnossov The code is in the second link

Comment: @JimStewart The code is in the second link

Comment: The code in the link has that as line 13, not 14.

Comment: @PavelAnossov I have added an extra line space between dt and the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely to be a python issue.

On a side not, there's a great shell function for executing scripts and redirecting output to vim buffer (split window).

Syntax to execute current script (you should have chmod +x and shebang line):

```
:Shell ./#
```

In order to add the function, add this to `.vimrc`:

```
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:RunShellCommand(<q-args>)

function! s:RunShellCommand(cmdline)
  let isfirst = 1
  let words = []
  for word in split(a:cmdline)
    if isfirst
      let isfirst = 0  " don't change first word (shell command)
    else
      if word[0] =~ '\v[%#<]'
        let word = expand(word)
      endif
      let word = shellescape(word, 1)
    endif
    call add(words, word)
  endfor
  let expanded_cmdline = join(words)
  rightbelow new
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap
  call setline(1, 'You entered:  ' . a:cmdline)
  call setline(2, 'Expanded to:  ' . expanded_cmdline)
  call append(line('$'), substitute(getline(2), '.', '=', 'g'))
  silent execute '$read !'. expanded_cmdline
  1
endfunction
```

https://github.com/ruslanosipov/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc#L137

Comment: I added the above to my vimrc and then ran the code with the shebang line of #!/usr/bin/ env python but received the following error:  Error detected while processing BufWinEnter Auto commands for "*":
E32: No file name
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: No space between `bin/` and `env`: `#!/usr/bin/env python`. Try doing `:Shell ./%`

Comment: that was a typo.  now it says Error detected while processing BufWinEnter Auto commands for "*":
E32: No file name
Error detected while processing function <SNR>7_RunShellCommand:
line   20:
E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h": $read !./%
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: @dustin Are you sure you don't have other entries in `.vimrc` interfering with the workflow?

Comment: I have other entries for latex in my .vimrc

Comment: @dustin I suggest either showing your vimrc or debugging it yourself by removing/adding configuration piece by piece.

Comment: added vimrc to original post

Comment: @dustin, lines 2 and 3 of your `.vimrc`, replace `*` with `?*` and hit the `:Shell ./#` again. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1639591

Comment: I made the necessary changes but I am still receiving the same syntax error as before now.